# While Loop with hasNextInt() actually reading?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hello my problem is with this program.

```
int integer = 0;
int evenInts = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
integer = in.nextInt();
while(in.hasNextInt()){
     System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
     integer = in.nextInt(); }
```

It should read in an int after "Enter an integer: " is asked. After that as long as integers are put in the input this procedure gets repeated.
Actually it prints something like this :

```
Enter an integer: 10
10 // so basically the
```

> "Enter an integer: "

message does not get printed this time

> Enter an integer: 12

If I leave away the `integer = in.nextInt();` code part before the while loop everything works fine. Why does the program behave like this? Is it because of buffering or a logical error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you have used up the only integer in your input stream and the `hasNextInt()` returns false because there is no next int in the input stream.

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
 integer = in.nextInt();// here you have read the int there is no more next int
```

you can use a do while loop

```
do{
 System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
 integer = in.nextInt(); 
 }while(in.hasNextInt());
```

Comment: But why can i scan for another int if the hasNextInt() method would return false?

Comment: 10 // so basically the //here you gave the next int

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a do-while loop:

```
do{
   System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
   integer = in.nextInt();
}while(in.hasNextInt());
```

Note that the values must be separated by spaces to continue the loop.