# first line of code in do...while loop skipped while entering the loop the second time - Java

Tags: java, loops

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] data = new int[10];
        int count = 0;

         do {
             System.out.print("Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: ");
             data[count] = input.nextInt();
         }
         while (input.hasNextDouble());
    }
}
```

output

```
Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: 2
4
Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: 6
Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: 8
```

My question is i don't know why the code jumps the `System.out.print("Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: ");` after `do {` when entering the loop the second time. This can be seen in second line of the output. Please what are my doing wrong?

I have searched for cases where my question might have already been answered but was only able to find solutions relating to code skipping `nextLine()`

Comment: Why do you check whether there is another double in the stream when you're reading integers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While Loop with hasNextInt() actually reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633931/while-loop-with-hasnextint-actually-reading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah your while loop is waiting to see if input hasNextDouble()

how can it know until your user has entered the next double or hit ctrl-z?

you'll have to do something Ugly like

```
System.out.print("Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: ");
do {
  data[count++] = input.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: ");
}
while (input.hasNextDouble());
```

note the count++ above as well i think it fixes another bug.

Comment: thanks a lot, because of your answer I've now understood where my problem is from. Am so greatful :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is first time `do` block is executed and then check for condition in `while`.

About `hasNextDouble()` in [orcale doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt(int)):

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as a double value using the nextDouble() method. The
>   scanner does not advance past any input.

As a solution you can change the condition like below:

```
do {
     System.out.print("Enter a number or ctrl + z when you are done: ");
     data[count] = input.nextInt();
     count++;
 }
 while (count < 10);
```

Also:

If you are using `input.nextInt();`, better to check using [`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt(int)).

Comment: I've left my downvote there because I don't think you answered the question.  OP asked "My question is i don't know why the code jumps ..." and "... Please what are my doing wrong?".  I don't think you've dealt with either of those questions.  Your first sentence "The reason is first time do block is executed and then check for condition" is entirely incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the first call to `input.hasNextDouble()` waits for a number to be entered before proceeding.

So the message in the *second* iteration of the loop won't appear until `input.hasNextDouble()` at the end of the *first* iteration of the loop has run - which of course fetches the second number.

You need to print the message *before* you call either `hasNextDouble` or `hasNextInt`.